# JQuery modal dialog HTML not updating

Tags: jquery

After clicking a button in my modal JQuery dialog, I want to update the html in the dialog to show text and an image indicating that work is in progress (spinner, etc.). When I do in the example below, the html doesn't update. It's as if that code never executes, or executes too late so the change isn't visible. However if I uncomment the alert('hey'); code, it does. What are good ways to achieve what I'm after?

```
$dialog.dialog( "option", "title", 'Do lengthy work' );
$dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", {

    "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
    "Start Work": function() {

        $(this).html('Working...<p/><img src="http://mydomain.com/progress.gif"');
        //alert('hey');
        doLengthyWorkFunction();
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }
} );
$dialog.html('Click the Start Work button to begin.');
$dialog.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

A `setTimeout()` call will free the system to update the display:

```
$dialog.dialog( "option", "buttons", {

    "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
    "Start Work": function() {

        $(this).html('Working...<p/><img src="http://mydomain.com/progress.gif"');
        setTimeout( function() {
            doLengthyWorkFunction();
            $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            0
        );
    }
} );
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but wouldn't $(this) be the button element when used in the click handler?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `doLengthyWorkFunction` does, but if it's making an ajax request then the work is being done asynchronously, and thus the actual call to `$.get` or `$.post` or whatever is finishing almost instantaneously.

If that's the case, then you'd want to have the dialog close code happen in the ajax success function instead of the dialog button click event.